# Bespoke responsive grid

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, grid

**Background**: I'm attempting to build a mobile first responsive website. In doing so, I'm creating my own grid system (3 column layout).

I'm using min media queries to change the size of each column depending on the viewport size.

---

**Question:** Is this the best way to tackle the problem? i.e. overriding the % widths of each column depending on the viewport size?

I was wondering if this is the 'Boostrap approach' OR if there's a cleaner more efficient way to create the column widths / grid system ?

---

**Code:** Each column in the grid is assigned a=one of the classes below.

```
.span_2_of_2 {
    width: 100%;
}

.span_1_of_2 {
    width: 49.2%;
}


/* 3 COLUMN */

.span_3_of_3 {
    width: 100%; 
}

.span_2_of_3 {
    width: 66.13%; 
}

.span_1_of_3 {
    width: 32.26%; 
}


@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {

.span_1_of_2, .span_1_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_3_of_3,  
.span_1_of_4, .span_2_of_4, .span_3_of_4, .span_4_of_4 {
    width: 100%; 
}

.col 
{
    margin: 1.9% 0;

}
} /*/mediaquery*/ 



@media screen and (min-width: 580px) { 


.col {
    margin: 0% 0 9% 1%; /* Spaces Columns */
}   

.span_1_of_2 {
    width: 49.2%;
    position: relative;
}

.span_1_of_3 {
     width: 32.26%;    
}
} /*/mediaquery*
```

Many thanks,

Comment: Recommend you read this: http://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-it-grids/

And your media-query is backwards - the way you have written it all your columns will be 100% wide on devices with a min-width of at least 300px.

Comment: Hello Sven, thanks for the info. The grid seems to work. On a device with a width of 300px (or more) the columns are 100%.  When the screen is stretched  beyond 580px, the columns shrink and float left, creating either a 2 or 3 column layout - Have I missed something obvious or made a mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

You have created a grid, then overwritten it with a min-width media query at 300px, which is going to be nearly all devices, so the first set of styles you wrote are almost always going to be ignored.

I take it from your code you are looking for the grid to kick in at 560px width - this works though you need to add float left and tweak your percentages a bit.

I have rejigged your code a bit:

```
<div class="col first span_1_of_3 blue">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col span_1_of_3 red">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="col span_1_of_3 green">&nbsp;</div>

/* Temporary styles for the example */
.blue {
  background: blue;
  min-height: 120px;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  min-height: 120px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  min-height: 120px;
}

/* The Grid */

/* Start at mobile and move up using min-width queries */
.span_1_of_2, .span_1_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_3_of_3,  
.span_1_of_4, .span_2_of_4, .span_3_of_4, .span_4_of_4 {
  width: 100%;
}

/* First breakpoint is 580px */
@media screen and (min-width: 580px) {

.col {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 20px 1%; /* Spaces Columns */
}

.first {
  margin-left: 0;
}

/* Two columns */
.span_1_of_2 {
  width: 49%;
}

.span_2_of_2 {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Three columns */
.span_3_of_3 {
  width: 100%; 
}

.span_2_of_3 {
  width: 65.3%; 
}

.span_1_of_3 {
  width: 32.65%; 
}

} /* End media query */
```

CodePen of old code here: http://codepen.io/simoncmason/pen/GgQPRa
CodePen of new code here: http://codepen.io/simoncmason/pen/yyvGyg

All columns are 100% wide up to screen widths of 560px, then the media query kicks in and breaks it into columns of the specified widths.

I have added a first class to remove the left margin from the first column.

I have changed the bottom margin from a percentage to px for more consistency.

I have rejigged the widths of columns slightly - though these would need refining for a production site.